# How to ask if someone wants to continue farming a boss in game / Interrupt to leave

Tags: politeness, phrase-requests

My attempt at both:

> A: ボスと戦い直したいか？
>   
> Do you want to keep going? (Fight the boss again?)
>   
> B: ちょっと・・・
>   
> Well... (I don't think I can)

But if I have to leave because of an emergency or about to go somewhere without wifi in real life, but nobody is asking me if I can keep going... how do I interrupt and let them know politely I can't stay for the next round?

Would this work?

> すみません,行かなきゃいけません,
>   
> (Sorry I have to go)

Comment: This looks like it could be divided into two separate questions.....

Comment: I can split this question if it's required. I just thought they were pretty closely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone asks you if you want to keep going, responding to them that you 'have to go' will tell them that you want to continue playing. 'I have to go' does not mean 'have to leave' in Japanese, unless you say where you have to go rather than forward. Instead of いかなきゃ you should say something else.

The reason you give and the detail that you provide is up to you and your relationship with the other player. Here are a few examples of phrases you can use which are polite enough but not overly specific.

Sorry I can't. すみません、これ以上できない。

I have plans. ちょっと用事があってね。

I shall retreat. 撤退/退却させていただきます。 or 撤退/退却いたします。

I have something else I need to do. 他にやらなきゃいけないことがあってね。

Sorry, have to 'go'. ごめん。バイバイしなきゃ。

Cap any of the above with 失礼します and you should be fine.

---

Asking if someone wants to continue farming/fighting, I would suggest the following:

Won't you go again? もう一回しませんか？

Won't you restart/retry? やり直しませんか？

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use...

> 「[落]{お}ちます。」
>   「そろそろ落ちます。」
>   「今日はもう落ちます。お疲れ。」 
>   etc...

(この「落ちます」はネットスラングだと思います。)

---

参考：

> (2)ゲームを終了すること。「今日は疲れたのでもう落ちます。」などと使われる。
>   ([goo辞書-NTTコミュニケーションズ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/olg/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8B/m0u/))