# 「と使う」ってなぜ「を」じゃなくて「と」なのですか？

Tags: particle-と

I sometimes see 「と使う」instead of 「を使う」. My understanding was that the only occasion where「使う」takes 「と」is with 引用, as explained [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8/#jn-154670).

> （文や句をそのまま受けて）動作・作用・状態の内容を表す。引用の「と」。

For some examples, we don't have to look very far:

> [補説]... 仮定形「たら」は、多く「ば」を伴わないで「雨が降ったら中止だ」などと使われ、「遅いからもう帰ったら」のように文末に用いられて8の意を表す。([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29766/what-does-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-do-at-the-end-of-a-sentence/29777#29777))
>
> ゲームを終了すること。「今日は疲れたのでもう落ちます。」などと使われる。([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59925/how-to-ask-if-someone-wants-to-continue-farming-a-boss-in-game-interrupt-to-le/59931#59931))
>
> 昔、TBSの番組「ザ・ベスト10」で久米宏が なに気に 「〜かしら」と言ったのを見て初めは かなり衝撃でしたが アナウンサーの業界では以外と使われている様です。([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-situations-where-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%82%89-is-considered-appropriate-normal-for-males-to/744#744))

But I just saw this:

> 呼びタメと使っているけど、意味を理解してない☆彡 ということでいいのですかね？？ ([source](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1098935240))

It sounds a bit odd to me. I thought, "For sure it should be 「呼びタメを使っている」, right?" So why is 「と」used here? And in general when should I use「と使う」instead of「を使う」?

And I am also wondering: with 引用, can I use「を」too? e.g. その文には "what" を使えません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, this person made a typo while trying to write 呼びタメという言葉を使っている or 呼びタメと言っている.

呼びタメ**を**使っている makes little sense in that context (she's gotten keigo replies).

Comment: Ah I see! Could you please also answer the last line and talk about を使う and quotations?

Comment: @EddieKai "You can't use (the word) X in that sentence" is その文ではX(という言葉)を使えません. You don't need a quotative-と.

Comment: It is clear to me now! ありがとうございます！I don't know why I used "に"... "で" makes more sense.